# Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got keyword DELETE at [6:1]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
--DELETE DUPLICATE VALUE IF HAVE TO
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ride_id ORDER BY started_at) AS row_num
  FROM `case-study-1-bike-share.bike_share.202102`
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

I want to delete duplicate value but received the following error instead. How do i fix this?

Comment: Your SQL implementation does not allow delete from a CTE. You could use `EXISTS()` instead.

Comment: But I want to delete rows from a table not checking it

Comment: So you want to delete all **except** the first (per ride_id ?)

Comment: You could do it like:

Delete from `case-study-1-bike-share.bike_share.202102` where ride_id in 
(
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ride_id ORDER BY started_at) AS row_num
  FROM `case-study-1-bike-share.bike_share.202102`
)
Select ride_id from cte
WHERE row_num > 1
)

Comment: Yup, delete duplicate rows except for the first unique value for column ride_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all SQL implementations allow modifyable CTEs. But you do not need them (in this case).

You could use `EXISTS(...)` to check of older observations exist for the same `ride_id`) . If older ones exist for `this`, `this` cannot be the oldest, and can be deleted.

---

```
-- DELETE DUPLICATE VALUE IF HAVE TO
DELETE FROM "case-study-1-bike-share.bike_share.202102" d
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM "case-study-1-bike-share.bike_share.202102" x      -- same table
        WHERE x.ride_id = d.ride_id                             -- same ride
        AND x.started_at < d.started_at                         -- but older date exists
        )
        ;
```